# Red dot in review dropdown menu

Tags: support, user-interface

From time to time, entries in the review dropdown menu are marked with a red dot and bold font for me instead of the usual gray dot:

[image]

Even after doing the reviews and reloading the page this highlight doesn't disappear (it eventually goes away, not sure what triggers that, though). Can anyone explain why that happens? Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: The red dot is almost certainly a feature.  My hypothesis is that it appears red when the number of entries reaches a certain number; my guess is that the number is 5.  Why it doesn't disappear when that number of entries is no longer visible to the participant is a mystery; *that* may be a bug.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226 (found via https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355233, https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4751). Apparently the dot should warn people that a queue is unusually long and needs attention. On lower-volume sites like this the dot almost always looks out of place (if it shows).

Comment: @barbarabeeton the dot indicates the queue status, as described here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dots-within-the-review-queue-drop-down/8387#8387 But it is strange, that like for siracusa, it doesn't go away for me, after doing all reviews, hence I would also like to know, if it is a bug that can be addressed?