# What is the meaning of the dots within the review queue drop-down?

Tags: support, closed-questions, review-page

Why is the grey circle of the closing request in my account very frequent in REVIEW QUEUES compared to other items? Is there a specific reason or is it something random?

EDIT by comments:

**First image**

[image]

**Second image**

[image]

Comment: Hi Sebastiano! Perhaps add a screenshot (I did not see a grey circle in my account yet).

Comment: If you look at the [close stats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) page, you will see that there have been 113344 close reviews (at the time of writing this answer) so far in this site, while the second most reviewed item is "First Posts", with 66180 reviewed so far. So you receive much more reviews from the "Close Votes" queue than from the rest because there _are_ more reviews in this queue.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Precious Stefan, hi from the hot Sicily. Now there's no gray dot on close voters. But the closing frequency is greater than all the others. I was thinking that probably the system chooses users based on their reputation?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ciaooooo :-) I've been registered for almost 3 years and I don't know the site as well as you do. I actually always use what I know. I happened to understand the flags how they work after a year (for example).

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Hi Stefan I have added two screenshots. My best wishes and good work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but the gray dot signals new reviews to do on a specific queue. Some queues have more activity than others, so consequently the dot will appear more often on one queue than on others. Of course you need a certain reputation level to be able to do reviews, but once you have reached that level, I don't think there are extra criteria according to which the reviews are presented to you.

Comment: @siracusa Thank you very much for everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A grey dot appears next to the review queue if there is something to review in that queue. This grey dot turns red if there is a sufficiently large number of reviews within that queue, denoting some urgency in reviewing that specific content. At that time, the actual review queue button also gets a red dot. Here is that view on [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com):

[image]

The [Reopen Votes review queue](//stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) (at that time) had a large number of reviews that needed addressing:

[image]

The review queues on TeX.SE is not that congested and therefore have the occasional grey dot, but rarely a red dot:

[image]